# $a_n$ is the number of sequences with length $n$ over ${1,2,3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recursion

$a_n$ is the number of sequences with length $n$ over ${1,2,3}$ such as there ain't no two number '1' next to each other.

Find a formula for $a_n$.

I thought about splitting it to one case where number in the last place was one, so the following must be 2 or 3 and a case where the three options are available. I'm having hard time putting it into formula and in general approaching those kind of questions.

I looked into other questions up here and still had hard time putting the concepts into this one.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call a sequence of $1$'s, $2$'s, and $3$'s "valid" if it doesn't have two consecutive $1$'s. Every valid sequence of length-$n$ fits one of these cases:

A) [valid sequence of length $n-1$], $2$

B) [valid sequence of length $n-1$], $3$

C) [valid sequence of length $n-2$], $2$, $1$

D) [valid sequence of length $n-2$], $3$, $1$

By considering these cases, can you find the number of valid sequences of length-$n$ in terms of the number of valid sequences of lengths $n-1$ and $n-2$? i.e. find $a_n$ in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$.

After doing that, you'll have a recursive formula for $a_n$. From there, you just need to come up with some initial values and solve the 2nd order linear recursion.

Comment: I didn't understand the way you split it into A,B,C,D

Comment: The four cases are: sequences ending with 2, sequences ending with 3, sequences ending with 2,1, and sequences ending with 3,1. It's not hard to see that these cases cover all valid sequences, and that no valid sequence is part of more than one case.

Comment: Can I split it into 3 cases, where $a_n+1$ is 2 or 3 so it'll be $2a_n$ and a case where $a_n+1$ is 1 so it has only 2 options? And finally I get : $a_n+1$ $=$ $2a_n$ $+$ $2a_n-1$

Comment: Yes, that works. Your method is basically the same, except you treated two of the cases I had as one. Regardless, you obtained the correct recursive formula.

Comment: I just checked the answers and they got $a_n$ $=$ $2a_{n-1}$ + $2a_{n-2}$, How different is that and why?

Comment: Also they mention for every $n$ $\ge$ $2$, why?